# Security integration of ModeShape JCR with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, integration, credentials, modeshape

How to integrate ModeShape JCR  with Spring MVC security credentials?

Where does ModeShape store user data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Authentication+and+authorization), ModeShape has a pluggable authentication and authorization system. ModeShape has built-in support for JAAS and Servlet security, but it does not have support for Spring MVC out of the box. Adding [custom implementations](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Custom+authentication+providers) is pretty straightforward.